# replace urlpath in php

Tags: php

I am new to php.

I am getting default image path as \xampp\htdocs\Sample\tmp/one.jpg

and i have to replace \xampp\htdocs with http:\localhost

If i use in this way i am getting required output

```
$absolute = "\xampp\htdocs";
$relative = "http:\\localhost";
$imagepathurl = "\xampp\htdocs\Sample\tmp\/safety-masks_5092610ad4f3f.jpg";

echo str_replace($absolute,$relative,$imagepathurl);
```

But i am getting the $imagepathurl from database. If i use this in same formate i am not getting result

```
$absolute = "\xampp\htdocs";
$relative = "http:\\localhost";

$imagepathurl = '"'.$imagepath.'"';
echo str_replace($absolute,$relative,$imagepathurl);
```

Comment: What is var_dump($imagepathurl);
saying? If str_replace isn´t replacing the path, than it just didn´t find any occurences
of "\xampp\htdocs" in the string.

Comment: Are you on LINUX or Windows ?

Comment: You should not store full file path in your database. If you do this, you will have problems when you move your code/data from one server to another (development to production server for example).

Answer (score 0):

In the secound listing when you add `"` before and after the `$imagepath` why?

Remove this line `$imagepathurl = '"'.$imagepath.'"';` and it should work:

```
$absolute = "\xampp\htdocs";
$relative = "http:\\localhost";

echo str_replace($absolute,$relative,$imagepath);
```

**Update (Example what the line does)**

```
$var = "MyString";   // Content of the String => MyString
$var = '"'.$var.'"'; // Content of the String => "MyString"
```

Comment: `$imagepath` is already a string, you add `"` before and after your string. (Added an example)

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [`pathinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get an array as result with all the components of your path.

Then you can replace the part that you want to change and concatenate the path components again to get the desired new path.

The way commented in the other posts is just a string manipulation solution. If you want something safe when dealing with parsing paths you should use the php function `pathinfo`. If is some quite simple then the `str_replace` will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your database does not applies any character encoding on string if it applies any then first decode the sting value and then use this code.

```
$absolute = "C:\xampp\htdocs";
$relative = "http:\\localhost";
// if database contains encoded string decode first here
//creating absolute path for image (this will remove ./, ../ \, / to create operating system preferred path as windows uses \ and linuz user / as path separator ) 
$imagepathurl = realpath($imagepathurl);
// replasing absolute path to root directory with relative path
echo str_replace( $absolute , $relative , $imagepathurl);
```